# PHP authentication library, how to build and configure it?

Tags: php, authentication, configuration

The Title may not be as clear but Il explain what's my problem.
Im building PHP MVC framework for my project. I know there are awsome PHP frameworks, but I like to code and Im doing this to learn more about PHP and MVC and other OOP patterns.
It works great, at least components I built so far.

I use PHP 5.3 and namespaces, so I can require/load classes based on their namespaces/names.
I built SPR-0 class loader class and it enables me to use other libraries that use SPR-0 "standard"/convention like Doctrine or Symfony2 components inside my framework. And all functionality of the framework itself, i call it Core, is writen as a component. So i have \Core\Controller\Controller() class or \Core\Router\Dispatcher() class or \Filesystem\FileManager() class. So I use them where I need them. And Core components enables me to add routes, detect them, call aproppriate controller/action etc... to build an MVC basicly.

And now I need Authentication modul to check if user is loged in on protected pages.
How do I setup that? The bigest problem is how do I tell Authentication Module what tables to use? Where to find usernames and where to find passwords? How do I configure Authentication module, so it knows where to look for username and password?
I could setup users table in database and never change it, and then instruct Authentication where to find stuff he needs. But what if on next project I would like to use different database design, and i would like to use email row instead of username?

Hope you understand whats bothering me...

The short question is how to setup Authentication class/module so you can configure it later to use other rows to fetch data from, and how flexible can that class can be, as far as configuration goes? Should I map some where in configuration that variable username maps to table users row username, so i can change it latter to email? How do you build flexible and configurable Auth library?

The question is long, so thanks for reading...

Comment: See the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), you could also provide multiple configuration / backend providers for your authentication component. Then use a dependency injection container so you can store the configuration in a central place per each project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to choose different DB tables for Auth depending upon what project you're working in...

Well why don't you create a **config file** that gets 'read' by the framework first thing?

That's what other frameworks do I think. You provide host,dbname,user and so on... In your case you'd, in addition to that, write in the config what tables and fields to use for authentication/auhorization?